# Bind after unbind on hover div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this div .overlay and when it is clicked the mouseenter and mouseleave is disabled by unbind and that works fine.

Now I want mouseenter and mouseleave back again (bind) on the ".overlay" div when I hover over div .container but that does not happen.

**Here is my code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".overlay").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });
    $(".container").hover(function(){
        $(".overlay").bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });   
});
```

Hope somone can help, many thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to bind and unbind the events? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: .overlay is an animated div, it moves out of view when clicked so it is moving away from the mouse pointer and if I do nut use Unbind mouseleave the div is comming back into view again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) you are actually unabling the event by removing the handlers on that event. I don't know what you want to fire when you `mouseenter/mouseleave` on '.overlay', but let's say you want to change the font color like so:

```
    $(".overlay").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css({color: 'red'});
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css({color: 'black'});
    });
```

Then you unbind (unbinding works), but somehow rebinding does not? It does actually but the previous bound execution on that event was already removed so you will need to rebuild it. A solution would be to put it in a `function` and call that function to rebind event.

Check this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJWks/).

Comment: This example on jsFiddle is also a very good solution, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

The bind event requires a function to actually run.  I took your code and added two bits, a logger of mouse events and something which resets the log:

```
$(".overlay").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $("#messages").html("unbound");
});

$(".container").hover(function(){
    $(".overlay").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', 
        function(){ $("#messages").append("mouse event");});
});
```

You can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/E8LY9/.  Your code seems to do everything right except the callback for mouseenter and mouseleave.

After a bit it struck me that you want container to be completely separate from overlay so I updated the fiddle to have them as separate elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/E8LY9/2/

Comment: unbind does not work, as one can see in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Sure it does.  In revision 2 you will see the #messages paragraph updated.  You just have to avoid hovering over container after you click overlay.